# How to stop LaTeX stretching my footnote

Tags: formatting, footnotes, urls

I've ran into a problem I can't seem to fix. So I've been working on a document, everything is as it's supposed to be, apart from one small detail.

I referenced certain parts of my text with `\footenotemark[]` and obviously used `\footnotetext[]` as a reference.

Only issue is, it stretched out to fit the width of the page.

Picture below:

[image]

Any way to prevent these spaces from happening?

Comment: since the MWE is missing, my best suggestion is: put more text in it?

Comment: You need to get some help on breaking URLs. But we don't know how you are including URLs so it is hard to help. (Note that it is unlikely to be due to the `\footnotemark`/`\footnotetext` usage.)

Comment: @jon I've just pasted them in the text. Is there any better way to include them?

Comment: Load the package `hyperref` (which includes many options) via `\usepackage{hyperref}` and then write `\url{<url>}`.  You may prefer to use the `colorlinks` option -- e.g., `\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}`. Note also that you typically load `hyperref` as the last (barring a few exceptions) package in your preamble because it does a lot of work behind the scenes.

Comment: Note that the image you posted doesn't really show anything related to `biblatex`, so you might want to check if you actually use that package (and if so, if it has something to do with your question) and want to edit the tags accordingly so as to not confuse future visitors and those trying to help you.

Comment: BTW: if you link to CTAN it is normally preferred to give the link via the generic `http://mirrors.ctan.org/` and not to a specific mirror.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you load the `url` package with the options `hyphens`, `spaces`, and `obeyspaces`, issue the instruction `\urlstyle{same}`, and then encase all URL strings in an `\url{...}` wrapper. That way, LaTeX will almost surely find a decent linebreak in the URL string and won't need to stretch the interword whitespace in earlier part of the footnote.

---

*Update, April 2022*: Six years ago, I recommended running

```
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
```

In the meantime, the [xurl](https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl) package has been released. It allows line breaks at arbitrary points in a URL string. Hence, I think it's time to replace the vintage-2016 recommendation with the following one:

```
\usepackage{xurl}
```